# SQL Server Join tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

[image: SQL SERVER JOIN]

I want each student's name, last payment date only. means only day.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Hey bro add some more details like Table,Sample Data and expected output right?

Answer (score 0):

I know i won't help you at all giving this code:
But you could try to learn something from it.

```
SELECT S.Id, S.Name, F.max_date, F.FeeAmt
FROM tbl_student As S
INNER JOIN (
SELECT t.Id, MAX(t.Date) As max_date, t.FeeAmt FROM tbl_fees As t GROUP BY t.Id
) As F ON F.Id=S.Id
```

First we selected all users from tbl_student, and then we are joining fees, selecting max date and grouping by user. The result is last (date) fee per user.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query. I hope this should give you the expected output:

```
SELECT S.Name, T1.LastPaymentDate 
FROM 
(SELECT Id, Max([Date]) AS LastPaymentDate from tbl_fees GROUP BY Id) AS T1 
INNER JOIN 
tbl_student AS S 
ON T1.Id = S.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S.name,SUB.LAST_DATE
FROM tbl_student S
JOIN (SELECT f.id AS ID,MAX(f.Date) AS LAST_DATE
      FROM tbl_fees f
      GROUP BY f.id) SUB
ON SUB.id = S.id
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.